# How can I show contents of iframe scaled by 50% for mobile device

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe

I have an iframe embedded in a responsive wordpress site.  The iframe is an interactive web calculator that was designed to be viewed at 900px wide and 670. I am trying to use media queries in my wordpress site to specify css that will change the size of the iframe as well as scale the contents of the css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #calculator {  
    -ms-zoom: 0.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

My iframe is specified as

```
<iframe id="calculator" style="float: top;" frameborder="0" width="900" height="670" src="someurl" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The iframe has text before and after it.  The wordpress site gives the iframe shrunk down to 50% but on mobile phones, we see the full width and height of the iframe specified (900 and 670 px respectively).  I.e. the wordpress text may only take up 40-50% of the width while the right half of the screen is whitespace.  I tried to add

```
width: 450px;
height: 335px;
```

into the media query css for calculator, but this causes other problems.  The calculator is built to be responsive but I don't want it to be.  Changing the size of the iframe as specified makes the calculator elements move around and the aspect ratio of the entire calculator.

I want it to look like it would when the calculator is 900 by 670 px, just scaled down by 50%.  What's the best way to make the html in the iframe think it's being rendered on a screen bigger than 900px wide but actually rendered at 50% that size on a mobile screen?

Comment: Have you tried to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` to your header?

Comment: serge, yes, that's already included in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old?  Did you try this good old library ?

[FitText.js library](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js)